# How to deal with json response in django from external API

Tags: python, django

I am currently building a simple dashboard in Django using data from external API like Amazon SP-API.
I wonder how to keep the data in database and make django update the fields whenever the changes occur.
I am iterating over 100 accounts using different refresh tokens and getting clients orders and pushing into database.

My current model is :

```py
class VendorOrder(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    purchase_order_number = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    purchase_order_state = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default = "", null = True, blank = True)
    purchase_order_date = models.DateTimeField()
    last_updated_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
    window_start = models.DateTimeField()
    window_end = models.DateTimeField()
    selling_party = models.CharField(max_length = 100)   
    warehouse = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    item_sequence_number = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
    buyer_product_identifier = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default ="", null = True, blank = True)
    vendor_product_identifier = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default ="", null = True, blank = True)
    ordered_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null = True, blank = True)
    accepted_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null = True, blank = True)
    received_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null = True, blank = True)
    net_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null = True, blank = True)
    net_cost_currency = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default ="", null = True, blank = True)
    total_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null = True, blank = True)
```

Currently I'm running a cronjob that make a request to Amazon API and I'm using update_or_create django function to save rows in database.

```
VendorOrder.update_or_create()
```

There are two things that I'd like to ask:

1. I'm using two different endpoints to get window_start and window_end date
   (there is no endpoint with items and window dates in one) and i'm merging it into one dict and then saving to db. Should i create another model with dates and use purchase_order_number as foreign key?
2. Should I do the same with items? How to keep them up to date as accepted_quantity can change in time. (now I'm using endpoint with specified changed date so i get update when the purchase order is changed).
   I also created unique_constraint to track updates but I wonder if I should keep the whole Purchase Order as JSON Field and update it if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most probably responses from external APIs data is included in `body` of the response. So

```py
body = request.body.decode("utf-8")
```

Now it will be in string format and you have to convert it into usable format, so,

```py
import json
body = json.loads(body_unicode)
```

Now it will be in `dict` or 'list' type. And now you can use it easily.